# Convert local variable into global variable in java

Tags: java, scope

I am new to Java Programming and I am stuck as how to convert local variable into Class Variables. The way I knew is to declare the variable outside method, but the value of that variable is initialize inside a method, When I use that method outside the method, it gives me null. Please let me, how can I do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Read a tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) And don't stop there, follow up anything you didn't understand.

Comment: Where is the code you are talking about? FYI, there is no `global varaible's`  in java. You have to refer them as `instance member`

Comment: Thanks Suresh for correcting me. Inspite of "Global Variables" i must use, "Class Variables". Please let me the ways that I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create instance variable (member variables of class) for simplicity instead of local variable.

Comment: Thanks Ankur for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the variable outside a block, and set it inside the block. You will have access to it outside.

```
int myInt;
if(x > 10){
   myInt = x;
}
// You have access to myInt here;
```

vs

```
if(x > 10){
   int myInt = x;
}
// You Do Not have access to myInt here;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Set the value within the constructor of the class, and don't create a new copy of the same variable within a method (it becomes a locally scoped variable).

Comment: Thanks jmkgreen for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the trick is basically understanding the type of variables we have in Java :

1. Instance Variable ( non-static fields, declared inside a class and not methods(depending on what your aim is), They cannot be reinitialized,automatically initialized) e.g int x; int y; double number;
2. Static Variables (only one copy is created per class )
3. Local Variables ( only accessed within the method or class it has been declared - within its scope, common withing methods)

In this case what you will do is define an instance variable at the beginning of your class, then access it wherever within your system.

here is my example : i have a simple POJO `class BMI{

```
public double weight;

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public double height;


public BMI() {
}
```

My main Java Class ...

```
public class MainActivity {
    double weight;
    double height;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void calculateBMI(double mWeight, double mHeight){
        BMI myWeight = new BMI();
        BMI myHeight = new BMI();
        weight = mWeight.setWeight();
        height = mHeight.setHeight();
        Height = height;
        weight = weight;
//calculate your bmi

    }   `
```